# I'm trying to run OpenWhisk on a Kubernetes cluster, but installation pods produce an error

Tags: docker, deployment, containers, serverless, openwhisk

I'm trying to run Apache OpenWhisk on a Kubernetes cluster running in Docker, [as explained in the OpenWhisk documentation](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube), but when I reach the point were I'm supposed to wait until the "install-packages" pods complete, they instead fail or never initalize at all.

This is my .yaml file:

```
whisk:   
    ingress:
       type: NodePort
       apiHostName: localhost
       apiHostPort: 31001
       useInternally: false

nginx:   httpsNodePort: 31001

# A single node cluster; so disable affinity
affinity:
    enabled: false
toleration:
    enabled: false
invoker:
    options: "-Dwhisk.kubernetes.user-pod-node-affinity.enabled=false"
```

I have Docker and its custer running alright, `kubectl` has `docker-desktop` as its context. So I run the following commands:

1. `helm repo add openwhisk https://openwhisk.apache.org/charts`
2. `helm repo update`
3. `helm install owdev openwhisk/openwhisk -n openwhisk --create-namespace -f mycluster.yaml`

Then, `kubectl get pods -n openwhisk --watch` will show
[image]
and eventually the `Init:0/1` will turn to `Error`. Other `install-packages` will show up but they also eventually find error.

(Of course I've tried using `wsk property set --apihost localhost:31001` --auth `<auth provided by the docs` and then actually trying `wsk action create someAction action.js`, but that will merely return `Unable to create action 'test': Put "https://localhost:31001/api/v1/namespaces/_/actions/test?overwrite=false": x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match localhost`.)

I've been stuck with this for over a week! Please, any help will do, and thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your k8s setup has sufficient resources? You need 2vCPU and 4GiB memory for this setup as per the documentation.

Comment: I ask this because `pending` pods means the pods cannot be scheduled, which is almost always due to a lack of resources on the node it is trying to schedule on. And since some pods will depend on the other, it is possible the ones stuck in init are waiting for the others to move to `Running` state.

Comment: Additionally, you should check the [technical requirements](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/docs/k8s-technical-requirements.md) in the documentation that list more constraints for the setup. Most notably, supported k8s versions.

Comment: Also, try looking at the troubleshooting guide, especially [this entry](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#install-packages-error-error-package-update-failed) that discusses an issue with the `install-packages` pod. Which is something you're also experiencing.

Comment: Here's [another hint](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/docs/k8s-docker-for-windows.md#hints-and-tips) to verify PVC availability for the pods.

Answer (score 1):

When pods are stuck like this, there can be several reasons, be sure to start with the simplest ones first.

1. Make sure your k8s setup has sufficient resources. You need at least 2vCPU and 4GiB memory for this setup as per the documentation.
2. Make sure you're using the supported Kubernetes version (1.19, 1.20 or 1.21).
3. If some pods are failing, and you see DNS related issues when looking at `kubectl logs -f -n <namespace> <pod-name>`. Verify that the `apiHost` is reachable from inside the cluster. You can use [this guide](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#install-packages-error-error-package-update-failed).
4. Make sure that the `PersistentVolumeClaims` that the pods have, can be bound to `PersistentVolumes` in the cluster. Check this with `kubectl get pvc -A`. You should not see any PVC in state `Pending`. You most probably do not have dynamic provisioning setup, so you will have to create these volumes yourself. If this is too much, you can simply disable persistence in your OpenWhisk setup with [this guide](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-deploy-kube/blob/master/docs/configurationChoices.md#persistence).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Here's what I have:  
  
1. I don't think so. I gave Docker more resources just in case, and I checked with `kubectl describe node` and seems fine as far as I can tell.  
2. What about 1.24.1? It's the version Docker has.  
3. For some reason the command you provided doesn't find the pods I input. Following the guide I get `Can't find localhost...: No answer` several times  
4. All three elements in the list show status `Bound`  
  
Please forget my inexperience, what do these results mean?

Comment: Ah, it appears the hostname is a problem. Perhaps try setting `docker-desktop` as hostname. I believe that is the hostname set for your node, inside k8s, yes? If you run `kubectl get nodes`? Helm cannot resolve the hostname when installing packages and you're having issues.

Comment: Right! `kubectl get nodes` will return `The connection to the server kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` So I should change the hostnameApi in the .yaml file, right??

Comment: Okay so, if I change the yaml file, what happens is that a pod named `owdev-controller-0` enters a loop of `Running` → `Error` → `CrashLoopBackOff` → `Running`, etc.

Comment: This last error magically disappeared since yesterday. `kubectl get pods` will now return `docker-desktop Ready` and when I run the install command now different pods called `owdev-install-packages-xxxxx` will cycle through `PodInitializing` → `Running` → `Error` → `PodInitializing`. I don't know :(

Comment: Perhaps if you can look at the pod logs it will give a hint? It might be tricky since you generally attach the log stream to a pod and if it restarts it is replaced by a new pod, and your log stream becomes invalid :( But still, you can try to see the logs.